# How can add others Properties using useSession with TypeScript in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying add new properties using useSession(), and it's worked on the console.log, but There is an error about the type, as I'm using TypeScript.

UseSession() return, name, email and image, but I added the properties id, iat and exp to user together and send these information to back-end.

nextAuth

src/api/auth/[...nextauth]

> ```
> import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
> import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
> import axios from "axios";
>
> const nextAuthOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
>   providers: [
>     CredentialsProvider({
>       name: "credentials",
>       credentials: {
>         email: { label: "email", type: "text" },
>         password: { label: "password", type: "password" },
>       },
>
>       async authorize(credentials, _) {
>         const response: any = await axios.post(
>           "http://localhost:4000/auth/login",
>           {
>             headers: {
>               "Content-type": "application/json",
>             },
>             email: credentials?.email,
>             password: credentials?.password,
>           }
>         );
>
>         const user = response.data.data;
>         console.log("user", user);
>
>         if (user.id && user.token) {
>           return user;
>         }
>
>         return null;
>       },
>     }),
>   ],
>   pages: {
>     signIn: "/sign-in2",
>   },
>   callbacks: {
>     async jwt({ token, user }) {
>       token.user = user;
>       return token;
>     },
>     async session({ session, user, token }) {
>       session.user = {
>         ...session.user,
>         id: token.sub,
>         iat: token.iat,
>         exp: token.exp,
>         jti: token.jti,
>       } as {
>         name: string;
>         email: string;
>         id: string;
>         iat: number;
>         exp: number;
>         jti: string;
>         type: string;
>       };
>       // console.log(session);
>       return session;
>     },
>   },
> };
>
> const handler = NextAuth(nextAuthOptions);
>
> export { handler as GET, handler as POST, nextAuthOptions };
> ```

It's work, but when I use the useSession to catch the user information, the typeScript give a note:

```
Property 'id' does not exist in type '{ name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; }'.ts(2339)
```

console.log(data?.user.id) print "1", i just need configured the interface and include properties

{id: "string", iat: "number", exp: "number"}

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { Badge } from "./ui/badge";
import { ShoppingCartIcon } from "lucide-react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { CartContext } from "@/app/providers/cartProvider";
import CartItem from "./Cart-item";
import { Separator } from "@radix-ui/react-separator";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import axios from "axios";


const Cart = () => {
  const { data } = useSession();

  const { products, subtotal, total, totalDiscount } = useContext(CartContext);
  console.log(data?.user);

  const handleFinishPurchaseClick = async () => {
    if (!data?.user) {
      return alert("Fazer o Login");
    }
    const order = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/orders", {
      user_id: data?.user?.id,
    });
    console.log(order);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex h-full flex-col gap-4">
      <Badge
        className="w-fit gap-1 border-2 border-primary px-3 py-[0.375rem] text-base uppercase"
        variant="outline"
      >
        <ShoppingCartIcon size={16} />
        Carrinho
      </Badge>

      {products.length > 0 ? (
        products.map((product) => (
          <CartItem key={product.id} product={product} />
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>Você ainda não adicionou nenhum produto ao carrinho</p>
      )}

      {products.length > 0 && (
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-3">
          <Separator />

          <div className="flex items-center justify-between text-xs">
            <p>Subtotal</p>
            <p>R$ {subtotal.toFixed(2)}</p>
          </div>

          <Separator />

          <div className="flex items-center justify-between text-xs">
            <p>Entrega</p>
            <p>GRÁTIS</p>
          </div>

          <Separator />

          <div className="flex items-center justify-between text-xs">
            <p>Descontos</p>
            <p>- R$ {totalDiscount.toFixed(2)}</p>
          </div>

          <Separator />

          <div className="flex items-center justify-between text-sm font-bold">
            <p>Total</p>
            <p>R$ {total.toFixed(2)}</p>
          </div>

          <Button
            className="mt-7 font-bold uppercase"
            onClick={handleFinishPurchaseClick}
          >
            Finalizar compra
          </Button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

I've already put the new properties into next-auth, but it  didn't worked

node_modules/next-auth/src/core/types.ts

```
export interface DefaultSession {
  user?: {
    name?: string | null
    email?: string | null
    image?: string | null
    id?: string | number
    iat?: number
    exp?: number
  }
  expires: ISODateString
}
```

```
export interface DefaultUser {
  
  name?: string | null
  email?: string | null
  image?: string | null
  id?: string | number
  iat?: number
  exp?: number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom hook and adding custom properties as

```
// useCustomSession.ts
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export function useCustomSession() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  // Add the custom properties to the session
  if (session) {
    session.id = 'your_custom_id';
    session.iat = Date.now();
    session.exp = Date.now() + 3600 * 1000;
  }

  return { session };
}
```

and using in the component as

```
import { useCustomSession } from './useCustomSession';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { session } = useCustomSession();

  if (session) {
    console.log(session.id); // Access the custom properties
  }

  // ................
};
```

***not tested: this is an idea from AI for the prompts I gave based on errors and the code from docs*** please let me know if it is unhelpful happy to remove :)

Comment: Type 'ExtendedSession' does not meet constraint 'boolean'.ts(2344)

useSession return boolean, if user exist first.

```
(alias) useSession<boolean>(options?: UseSessionOptions<boolean> | undefined): {
    update: UpdateSession;
    data: Session;
    status: "authenticated";
} | {
    ...;
} | {
    ...;
} | {
    ...;
}
import useSession
```

Comment: my bad ... lets try another approach of making own custom hook *(not tested: this is an idea from AI for the prompts I gave)*